# CKEditor5 Text Alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am try to configure my page with the CK5 editor. I did:

```js
ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
  language: 'pt-br',
  toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote'],
  heading: {
    options: [{
      model: 'paragraph',
      title: 'Paragrafo',
      class: 'ck-heading_paragraph'
    }, {
      model: 'heading1',
      view: 'h1',
      title: 'Cabeçalho 1',
      class: 'ck-heading_heading1'
    }, {
      model: 'heading2',
      view: 'h2',
      title: 'Cabeçalho 2',
      class: 'ck-heading_heading2'
    }, {
      model: 'heading3',
      view: 'h3',
      title: 'Cabeçalho 3',
      class: 'ck-heading_heading2'
    }]
  }
}).then(editor => {
  console.log(editor);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

This works, but doesn't have an 'alignment' option. I found [this link](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/text-alignment.html) on how to install the @ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment package

I followed carefully the steps show in this link, I have installed the NPM package manager and was raised the 'node_modules' paste in my application,  but my browser report the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

from this line:

```
import Alignment from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment';
```

I'm not an expert in NPM, but followed the steps shown. I don't know what is 
missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own build in order to add some extra plugins. You cannot add plugins to ckeditor5 without building it.
More information:
[Ckeditor5 Custom Builds](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/development/custom-builds.html)

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to @Dariush Salami's answer, take a look at [this link](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/installing-plugins.html), and check if it'll help you.

If you would like to install plugins locally on your own machine, please see how this can be done [here](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/5699#issuecomment-549920121).